# Error executing bootstraps after upgrade from grails 1.3.7 to 2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Afer upgrading a grails application from 1.3.7 to 2.0, a java NullPointerException is being thrown (the complete error is below).

I'm using debian squeeze and java version OpenJDK "1.6.0_18", although have tried with prepackaged debian sun-jdk too.

I've tried to uninstall all the plugins with no luck; debugging mode does not give me a clue, either. I've also checked my datasource in development environment:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {

        dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
    //url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB"  //hsql
        url = "jdbc:mysql://server.domain/database" //mysql
        username = "user"
        password = "password"

    }
}
```

No luck at all.. any ideas? I've checked related posts, but cannot find the same problems here...

Thanks in advance

```
Error 2012-02-07 13:24:15,024 [Thread-11] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error         executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':     Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean     property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is     java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization     of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:     Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean     'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is     java.lang.NullPointerException
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    636 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager':     Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property     'sessionFactory'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is     java.lang.NullPointerException
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    636 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory':     Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    636 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    636 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for closing this issue, it was related to spring-security-plugin ugprade from acegi-plugin. I used spring-security-plugin default classes and properties and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BuildConfig.groovy
make sure the appropriate JDBC library has been enabled such as written in these line :

> dependencies {
>        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
>       }

Or if you prefer adding the library without dependent on Grails load library mechanism, just put your jar to /lib folder on your project

Answer (score 0):

I received similar errors by having the Java keyword `protected` in a .groovy domain class.  I just removed the `protected` keyword and it worked fine.  I imagine if I renamed the file to `.java`, it would have worked fine too.